# Running test before pushing in Golang

Tags: git, circleci

I've new git repo which written in Golang that and I connect it to circle ci
and this works as expected.

Now before I `push` to git I run the tests **manually** with `go test ./...`, and then I push it.
My question if this can be done **automatically ?** i.e. when I push to git the tests will automatically executed and and if something is wrong decline the `push` until the test will be fixed.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: fredrik, you should write that in an answer as that's the answer. Also, you can use the CircleCI CLI to run the entire build locally if you want.